# Redirecting to FTP URL with username and password in Safari

Tags: php, redirect, safari, ftp, http-headers

I've got a problem with Safari I haven't been able to solve:

```
<?php
    header("Location: ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip");
?>
```

This code-snippet works in every browser (Fx, Chrome, IE7-9), but not in the latest Safari, which tells me that I don't have permission to view the page (that is, it redirects to the correct page [somedomain.org] with the correct protocol, but does not process the authentication data).

Interestingly it works when I copy it directly to the address bar or when I put in in an `<a>`-tag an click on it. Is this a Safari bug, or am I missing something here, which the other browsers ignore? And if it's a Safari bug, is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: I am strongly wondering whether it is allowed to pass a username/password combination in a redirect. I tend to go with 'it is not allowed' and Safari is the only one properly implementing/preventing this security risk

Comment: Well, it is completely valid according to [rfc1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt), so Safari would be the only browser not obeying the standard. In addition, the only case it does not work is when using a HTTP location redirect, which makes it extremely unexpected behaviour at the very least.

Comment: Just for kicks, Safari can go to that URI if you type it in, yes?  Can it go there via a link on a page?

Comment: I would be curious to see what the web/FTP server says that the actual redirect request was . Perhaps safari is doing something to the redirect

Comment: @stimpy: I didn't think about that, but I will definitely check it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip');
```

if it doesn't work try :

```
echo <<< EOF
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip">
EOF;
```

Or:

```
header ('Location: ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip');   
header ('Content-Length: 0');
```

The last solution I got from: http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/90424/

Comment: The additional header did not work. The second might work, but is not applicable in my situation, because it'd redirect away from the current page before initializing the download.

Comment: Check if this works: 

header (“Location: ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip”);

header (“Content-Length: 0”);

Answer (score 0):

echo "window.location='ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip';";

Try that JS redirect and see if it's PHP or the request it has a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some header() info it needs like - header("Status: 200");... A while back header redirect did not work w/o this line in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the PHP script fetch the file in the background, and serve it to the browser. As in, the PHP script acts as a proxy. 
Assuming your download is not larger than your webserver's PHP mem limit, this will be OK.

Benefits:
-There is no redirect. 
-You would not be exposing the user/pass in the URL.

If redirecting to the pw protected FTP is your decision, consider the alternatives. There are lots of ways to secure access to a file via http. These days, HTTP performance is about equal to that of FTP (long ago this was not true, and fast sites needed FTP for downloading).

Comment: This is what I was doing previously. However, as the files served through the system tend to be very large, I moved to a hybrid system where large files are served through FTP and small files are passed directly by PHP.

Comment: ALSO - verify the MIME type is correct for ZIP. Double-check that (there's a lot of old/wrong info about MIME types on the web). I don't thing Safari is wrong, but just being extra picky/secure about redirection, as a ZIP

Answer (score 0):

do you receive any error or just not working?

make sure the the output buffer is set correctly in the phpconfig

Comment: I edited my question to make clearer what happens. Also I doubt this is an output buffer problem. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, and it turned out to be the keychain! If you ever allowed safari, omniweb or opera (or the ftp process in you case) to store the username and password in the keychain for that site, this will be sent to the site instead of the one in the URL. FireFox doesn't do this, so things work as expected there.